# Upgrading glibc in centos 6.6

Tags: linux, yum, centos-6, glibc

My server is using `glibc-2.12.x.` when I install certain packages it gives an error.Dependency not found `glibc-2.14` or above is required.When I try using `yum install glibc*` it says server is already installed with the latest version.

how can i upgrade to `glibc-2.14` or greater using yum updater?
Also is there any problem with using `glibc-2.14` without updating centos 6.6 to 7.

Thanks,
Vivek.

Answer (score 1):

Run `yum info glibc` to see what version of glibc is installed and what version is available.

`glibc-2.14` is not available to my CentOS 6.8 so I don't think you can use `yum` to upgrade it.

If you need to install new version of open source software (normal user only) then I highly recommend `Linuxbrew` everything is installed to your home directory.

Hope this helps

Comment: this will help me next time.